# You are not far from correct?

Tags: meaning

> You are not far from correct.

What does it mean? Does it mean ...

> You are absolutely correct.

or

> You are neither correct nor wrong.

That is,

> You are partially correct.

?

Comment: *You're not far from correct* isn't idiomatic. "valid" alternatives include ***You're almost correct / nearly right / close.***

Comment: It means you're wrong. It doesn't mean you're right. It just means that your answer is relatively close to right, like if I ask, "What's two plus two?" and you answer, "7,528,290," that is very far from correct, but if you instead answer, "Five," you're still wrong, but you're not as wrong, *not far from correct*, relatively speaking, i.e., a lot less far than if you'd answered, "7,528,290."

Comment: "Not far from" = "close to". So someone is close to being correct, but not exactly correct.

Answer (score 3):

"Not far from" is a synonym of *nearly* and *almost* and *mostly*. That means you aren't exactly right, but you are close to being right.

Comment: But "not far from correct" is not a common expression: I doubt I've ever encountered it before. It's meaning is nevertheless clear to a native speaker, as Jack says.

Comment: Thank you, Jack! Thank you, Colin! I appreciate your help.